# How to deactivate GridViewItem-click animation?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

How to **deactivate** the GridViewItem-click animation (shown below), **when right-clicking** a GridViewItem?

[image: GridViewItem-click animation]

**Edit:**
Code after Nate's suggestion (does not work). I added the VisualStates, but I still see the animation. However, selected items no longer have the blue border, since I added the `VisualStateGroup` element (which I don't care about, but the code has some effects).

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="MovieLibrary.VideoPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MovieLibrary"
    xmlns:common="using:MovieLibrary.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="pageRoot_Loaded">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:SetPercentageConverter x:Key="SetPercentageConverter"/>
        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">Hello, video!</x:String>

        <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <GridViewItemPresenter x:Name="gridViewItemPresenter" Padding="0" ContentMargin="0">
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"><Storyboard/></VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed"><Storyboard/></VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </GridViewItemPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="commandBar">
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SyncMovieLibraryButton" Icon="SyncFolder" Label="Sync Movie Library" Click="SyncMovieLibraryButton_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SetMovieLibraryButton" Icon="Folder" Label="Set Movie Library" Click="SetMovieLibraryButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>

    <GridView x:Name="videoGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}" Padding="0" RightTapped="videoGridView_RightTapped">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding PosterPath}" Loaded="Image_Loaded" Stretch="UniformToFill" RightTapped="Image_RightTapped" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Page>
```

Comment: In the [GridViewItem default styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx), specifically the bottom one, you'll notice there is a `StoryBoard` for the `Pressed` state which includes a `PointerDownThemeAnimation`. Copy the style, remove the `StoryBoard` (or just the animation), should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but: Nope, does not work. Could you check if I made a mistake?

Comment: It looks like `PointerOverPressed` may have a similar animation. Try overwriting that as well.

Comment: Can I ask, are you setting the `ItemContainerStyle` in the `GridView`? Or have you just defined a new `GridViewItemStyle` in your resources? Can we see your `GridView` declaration?

Comment: I added the complete XAML code for you.

Comment: Ah, it seems to me that you've combined the top default style and the bottom. Note that there are two `GridViewItem` styles on the linked page, one which uses the `GridViewItemPresenter` and one which does not. One thing to try is removing the visual states and instead overwrite the `ContentTransitions` property of the `GridViewItemPresenter`, as I think that's the most likely property to have the transition animation. Or, you could overwrite the whole style with the old version (copy and paste the bottom style from the page in). It still works, and you can remove the storyboards like before.

Comment: Hi @NateDiamond , thanks so much for your time! However, as a XAML beginner, I have difficulties understanding your latest response. Maybe you would give me a code example?

Comment: I added an answer which should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order to do it only for right clicking, you'll likely have to make a custom control that doesn't trigger pointer pressed state change on right click, but does on left click.**

**The next part is for left- *and* right-clicks:**

There are two things to try, based on your current Xaml.

In the [`GridViewItem` default styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx) there are two content templates, one which uses `GridViewItemPresenter` and one which does not.

First, try using the `GridViewItemPresenter` style, but overwrite the `ContentTransitions` property with a new `TransitionCollection`.

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <GridViewItemPresenter
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                    CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
                    CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
                    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
                    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"
                    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1"
                    ContentMargin="4" >
                    <GridViewItemPresenter.ContentTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </GridViewItemPresenter.ContentTransitions>
                </GridViewItemPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If that still doesn't work, then use the style below that one on the same page. It's too long to be placed here completely, so I have just added the fixed `VisualStateGroup` for `CommonStates`. If you go to the place I linked above, scroll to the section at the bottom, and copy all of it in, then collapse and overwrite the `CommonStates VisualStateGroup` block, it should work.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1" />
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
        <Storyboard/>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="1" />
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Duration="0"
                             To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Great, this helps. The animation is disabled now. However, also for left-clicking. Until I have not found a solution to this one, I cannot mark this as answered, but as helpful. If I find the solution, I add it to your answer and mark it answered. :) Thank you!

Comment: In order to do it only for right clicking, you'll likely have to make a custom control that doesn't trigger pointer pressed state change on right click, but does on left click.